# Google Apps Script to Output a JSON Array into a rows

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

sorry I just learned the app script and my english is not good. on the Google app script, based on the example of json array, how do I get `itemA` and `itemC` output?

```
{
    "items":[
        {
            "itemA":123,
            "itemB":"qwe",
            "itemC":"asd"
        },
        {
            "itemA":456,
            "itemB":"rty",
            "itemC":"fgh"
        },
        {
            "itemA":789,
            "itemB":"uio",
            "itemC":"jkl"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want the output like this :

```
123, asd
456, fgh
789, jkl
```

I really appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This script gives the output you want.
Happy?

```js
var json = {
  "items": [{
      "itemA": 123,
      "itemB": "qwe",
      "itemC": "asd"
    },
    {
      "itemA": 456,
      "itemB": "rty",
      "itemC": "fgh"
    },
    {
      "itemA": 789,
      "itemB": "uio",
      "itemC": "jkl"
    }
  ]
}
var output_text = "";
json.items.forEach(function(item) {
  output_text += item.itemA + ", " + item.itemC + "\n";
});
console.log(output_text);
```

Comment: `delete` deletes in-place. If the intent is modifying the original object, `forEach` is better suited for the iteration.

Comment: @Antoni, thank you for your answer, please check update of my question

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
let obj = {
    "items":[
        {
            "itemA":123,
            "itemB":"qwe",
            "itemC":"asd"
        },
        {
            "itemA":456,
            "itemB":"rty",
            "itemC":"fgh"
        },
        {
            "itemA":789,
            "itemB":"uio",
            "itemC":"jkl"
        }
    ]
};

function genOutput() {
  var output = obj.items.map( item => [item.itemA,item.itemC] );
  console.log( output );
};
```

Run function genOutput, you will get the following output:

```
[ [ 123, 'asd' ], [ 456, 'fgh' ], [ 789, 'jkl' ] ]
```